# Create array of checked checkboxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get an array of chechked checkboxes. 
So far I used the following code:

```
var data ={
td1_1_checkbox:  $("#table #tr1 #td1_1 #td1_1_checkbox").val(),
td1_2_checkbox:  $("#table #tr1 #td1_2 #td1_2_checkbox").val(),
td1_3_checkbox:  $("#table #tr1 #td1_3 #td1_3_checkbox").val(),
td1_4_checkbox:  $("#table #tr1 #td1_4 #td1_4_checkbox").val()
}
```

This code but only got me the value "on". I tried with .checked() but didn't get a result.

Comment: Please include your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.is(':checked')` to get the checked/unchecked state of checkbox. Also, since you have a unique `id` for each of the checkbox so you can simply use the `id` selector as `$("#td1_1_checkbox")`, `$("#td1_2_checkbox")` and so on.

```js
var data ={
  td1_1_checkbox:  $("#td1_1_checkbox").is(':checked'),
  td1_2_checkbox:  $("#td1_2_checkbox").is(':checked'),
  td1_3_checkbox:  $("#td1_3_checkbox").is(':checked'),
  td1_4_checkbox:  $("#td1_4_checkbox").is(':checked')
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='td1_1_checkbox' type='checkbox' checked='checked' />1
<input id='td1_2_checkbox' type='checkbox' checked='checked' />2
<input id='td1_3_checkbox' type='checkbox' checked='checked' />3
<input id='td1_4_checkbox' type='checkbox' checked='checked' />4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for. And you helped me even more with the ID. I thought since the checkbox was in a table I hade to select it through the DOM. Have a nice day!